# Understanding AsyncTask with web server accessing

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, android-asynctask, webserver

New programmer. Questions at the bottom.

I have an array of fleets that corresponds to vehicles. I would like to make successive calls to the server with each slot in my fleet array.

I wish to do this with an AsyncTask.

```
private class refreshTruckInformation extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Void> {


            @Override
        protected void doInBackground(URL... urls) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void... voids) {

        }
    }
```

**How do I pass in my array of fleets so that I can use them in my doInBackground?

I also want to have a progress bar that goes based on the percentage of fleets it has gone through. What is a good way to do this?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **How do I pass in my array of fleets so that I can use them in my doInBackground?

Remember that refreshTruckInformation is still a class. So you can use any constructor or settier methods to pass your array.

> I also want to have a progress bar that goes based on the percentage
>   of fleets it has gone through. What is a good way to do this?**

From your doInBackground method you can publis progress using `publishProgress` method. This progress parameter will be catched in `onProgressUpdate` method

**For example**

```
private class RefreshTruckInformation extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Void> {

        private int[] b;
        public RefreshTruckInformation (int[] a){
             // use array
             b = a;
        }

        public void setArray(int[] a){
             // use array
             b = a;
        }

            @Override
        protected void doInBackground(URL... urls) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void... voids) {

        }
    }
```

And call using

```
RefreshTruckInformation r = new RefreshTruckInformation (yourArray);
```

or call method like

```
r.setArray(yourArray);
```

and execute like

```
r.execute();
```

Comment: for some reason this weird set up is throwing me off. I know(i think i know) that you do not call these methods from anywhere. So how do I 'give' doInBackground my array?

does it have to do with when i call execute in main thread?

Comment: @benzabill I have given an example .. see if it can help your

Comment: Thank you! That was the mental gap I wasn't getting.

Comment: One more thing. So I now have this array, b. What do i do with the urls and progress parameteres in doInBackground and onProgressUpdate?

Comment: you can send the url in execute like before .. and use publishProgress to send progress. see the example here.... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Ok :) I see how  URL... urls would work because it's an array but should the other two be varargs too? how do I do it if they aren't and how do i if they are?